# How to write a crawler for a desk-top

Tags: python, perl

I'd like to write a program that indexes my pdf and music files on my hard drive(not server). I plan to do this via perl or python, or both. I'll basically be writing a crawler for my desctop. The user interface will be in JavaFx, which I think quite fluent in. I've done a couple of projects in JavaFx. I have not done anything in perl/ python. I however, have done a few lines of code in them while teaching myself the syntax.

The question is what topics should I start my research in when embarking on writing a crawler. I've seen quite a number of tutorials online on crawlers but all do web page indexing. Plus what modules should I look into?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please explain in one sentence: what is the question you are asking? General wondering and worrying is really difficult to answer in question/answer format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python to find the files you can use `os.walk` - the examples in the help are very helpful.

Assuming that you are looking to do more than just locate the files and get their names you will need to look into getting some more information about the contents, there are python libraries that can get text from pdf files such as PDFMiner and pdfquery.

Likewise there are numerous python tools that can get you some more information on your music files.

It all depends on how you are planning on indexing them.